# Any way to pass second parameter in exceptionHandler?

Tags: java, exception

Have a service method which can throw an exception

```
if (NOT_FOUND) {
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Resource not found");
}
```

And ControllerAdvice with exceptionHandler

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleResourceNotFound(Exception ex) {
  return new ResponseEntity("your-error-message");
}
```

So i need to pass another String as param and access it form exceptionHanlder:

```
if (NOT_FOUND) {
    String param2 = "param2";
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Recource not found", param2);
}


@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleResourceNotFound(Exception ex) {
  doomething(param2);
  return new ResponseEntity({your-error-message});
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Can you not create your own exception class?

Comment: i think it would make more sense to move the method call `doomething` to the place where it happens (inside of `if (NOT_FOUND){}`)

Comment: Just pass an object instead of a string

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as Abra said, you can create your own exception that inherits from ResourceNotFoundException, and add the other parameter there. Then in the exception handler you can get it from the exception:

This could be the class

```
public class CustomException extends ResourceNotFoundException {
  private String otherParam;

  public CustomException(String message, String otherParam) {
     super(message);
     this.otherParam = otherParam
  {
   public getOtherParam() {
     return otherParam;
   }

}
```

Then you throw it

```
throw new CustomException("Recource not found", param2);
```

Then in exception handler you can get the second param

```
@ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleResourceNotFound(CustomException ex) {
  doomething(ex.getOtherParam());
  return new ResponseEntity(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i refer to the [error handle tutorial (chapter 6.3)](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) , where you see an proper usage of the Exception Handler as you did in your code snippet.

there is an interesing aspect of your approach:

> Of course, we'll use the global exception handling mechanism that we discussed earlier to handle the `AccessDeniedException` as well:

so the purpose of your Exception Handler is to handle Exceptions of a vast variety of exceptions: **global exception handling**. You would not know where the exception was thrown. Therefor it makes no sense to add additional logic to your Exception handler on the Handler side.

rather than adding a backpack to the handler you should take the action on the point of existing. that would take a small archituetur change and handle there:

```
if (NOT_FOUND) {
    String param2 = "param2";
    doomething(param2);
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Recource not found");
}
```

### clean code - [separation of concerns](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Separation_of_Concerns_SoC)

- if it was a general aspect of exception handling, you would have the general informatiaon already in your hands
- if it is a specific aspect, then it should be handled where it happens!

Answer (score 0):

Just update your advice:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
// public ResponseEntity handleResourceNotFound(Exception ex) {
public ResponseEntity handleResourceNotFound(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
  // ex contains all parameters that you need
  return new ResponseEntity("your-error-message");
}
```